What is sameness?
I read this:

“There are four kinds of sameness (samata) for those who discipline
themselves in religious life: appearance, causation, coming into
being, and the fourth is egolessness.”

Can you describe the experience of "coming into being"?  Why is it sameness?
Do you think these four kinds of sameness are the same meaning described by four different concepts?

one para question. So what is different between upekkha and samānatā?

@enRaiser I think samata means equanimity, and samānatā means sameness

The dictionary gives samatā as "equality or evenness", and samatha as "tranquility, calm, quietude".

Saṃbhoga (संभोग, “love in union”)

Sameness (samta) means treating everyone or everything the same way.
Appearances , whether good or bad, should be treated with Samta(sameness).
Causation , good or bad , should be treated with sameness.
Coming into being , good or bad , should be treated with sameness.
Egolessness, resulting in good or bad , should be treated with sameness.
This is my guess. If you can provide the original script then I can give a more confident answer. I am not sure what is meant by egolessness in the context of Buddha’s teachings.
